# Overflow on divs?

Tags: html, css, web

I have created a three-column background type thing, as I previously described in my first question: [How to create a three-column website background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903474/how-to-create-a-three-column-website-background-using-css). Anyways, I have it working mostly successfully like so:

I have a div with id centercolumn, containing all my page's content (header, content, footer, etc.):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="centercolumn">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in CSS, I have the following settings (only showing the relevant code):

```
body {
    background-image: url('theimagetobetiledalongthesides.png');
}

#centercolumn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    width: 760px;

    background-image: url('theimagetobetiledalongthemiddlecontentcolumn.png');
}
```

Essentially, the body provides the background for the whole page, then the centercolumn div goes on top of that and stretches all the way down the page, and has a different background image. This gives the appearance of having three columns: one in the middle for content, and two on the sides.

I believe the issue I'm having is with the `overflow` property of the centercolumn div. On any browser I've tested with (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, and Safari), the center column initially goes all the way to the bottom of the page (as it should). When I vertically resize the page, making it smaller/shorter, once I reach the actual content (which is text), a scrollbar appears on the side of the page/browser (as it normally would). However, when I scroll down to see the rest of the content, it's as though the centercolumn div doesn't go all the way down: the different background image of the centercolumn stops part way down (exactly where the bottom of the browser was before I scrolled back down). My text runs out of the centercolumn background image, and on to the background image of the body.

When I set the overflow on the centercolumn div to be `scroll` and start resizing the page, it works fine (the div seems to go all the way down - the centercolumn background image doesn't cut off), but it creates a rather ugly effect where the scroll bar actually appears on the side of the middle content column rather than the side of the browser.

What can I do to get the middle content column's different background image to go all the way down, without causing a scrollbar to appear on the side of the middle column as I vertically resize the browser window?

*edit:* JSFiddle example at http://jsfiddle.net/dDfkC/1/.

Comment: can you show a working example of your code? maybe on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Ibu Ok, I have an example at http://jsfiddle.net/dDfkC/1/. I did it using colors rather than images, but it has the same effect (if you vertically resize your browser window to be smaller, you'll see when you scroll down the result panel on jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using position:absolute, which is wrong, you want to use relative positioning then margin:0 auto; to center this column.

What you need to do is set it

```
#centercolumn {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:760px;
    background-image: url(whatever);
    background-repeat: both;
}
```

And if you want it to expand to the bottom of the page, no matter how little content you have:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}
```

and add to above

```
#centercolumn {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

and a real basic CSS Reset:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly, but now the center column doesn't go all the way up to the top of the page, it stops a bit before the top. What can I do to make it go all the way up and down the page?

Comment: CSS reset, what you are seeing is the browsers default margin and padding... so add this to the start of your css:  * {margin:0; padding:0;}

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#centercolumn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    min-height:100%;

    margin: auto;

    width: 760px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url('theimagetobetiledalongthemiddlecontentcolumn.png');
}
```

Would probably be better to see an example of what you have and exactly what you would like to achieve

Comment: At http://jsfiddle.net/dDfkC/1/ you can see an example of my goal. I did it using colors rather than images, but it has the same exact effect. It's not a matter of background image repeating either, mine repeats both vertically and horizontally automatically (which is what I want, just vertically or just horizontally doesn't tile properly). In jsfiddle, you can see my basic idea: a center column with content, and two side columns with a different background design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed positioning for the left and right columns and static positioning for the main column, as in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDfkC/2/)

Comment: Except he doesn't have that markup what so ever at all; as well this will result in its own issues as his content grows and as he adds other elements into his container.

Comment: @Patrick JC That's the same markup except for the left and right columns I added; those columns are described [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903474/how-to-create-a-three-column-website-background-using-css), which was linked to in the first paragraph. Also, what issues would arise from this method?

Comment: You added two new divs and a ton of css to fix an issue that could be solved by using less css and not adding any html markup.  As well, lets say he fills this center column up with content (probably a good bet he plans to do this) giving the wrapper a static position can cause float issues and abosolute positioning issues.  As well, depending on his background image for the side bars, not letting those scroll naturally could make it look funny and cause issues, etc.  While your solution works, it introduces the potential for other issues, and he adds lots of extra code (realitvely speaking).

Comment: @PatrickJC If you [remove the html markup and almost all of the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/dDfkC/5/) my solution still works. I was just trying to help the person who asked the question by showing how it would integrate with what s/he described in the other question.